# How should I label the differentials (arrows) in sseq for a spectral sequence?

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, sseq

I'm trying to typeset a spectral sequence using the `sseq` package, which provides a way to place objects on a grid and draw arrows between them. I'd like to put labels on the arrows, as one can do with `xy-pic` and `tikz-cd`, but can't figure out how to do it in `sseq`, and [the package documentation](https://people.kth.se/~tilmanb/sseq.pdf) doesn't say anything about it.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sseq}

\begin{document}
\begin{sseq}[grid=none,labelstep=1]{0...2}{0...1}
  \ssmove{0}{1}
  \ssdrop{A}
  \ssarrow{2}{-1}
  \ssdrop{B}
\end{sseq}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

What I'd like to do is find a way to add a label to the arrow from *A* to *B*:

[image]

Is there a way to do this within `sseq`?

Comment: I see nothing in the manual that suggests it's possible.

Comment: @egreg: yeah, seems like it, so I'll probably just use TikZ. Thanks for checking, though!